# JS, span selecting returns empty list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a js code for my website that will contain multiple slideshows. In order to do this, I had to change my code and suddenly it isn't working anymore.

```
let dots = document.getElementById("slideshow" + String(slideshow)).getElementsByClassName("circle");
```

This should select all the span elements in the following HTML code:

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div id="slideshow0">
    <a class="back" onclick="changeSlide(-1, 0)">&#10096;</a>
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="../../img/IMG_3729.JPG" id="img_1" alt="Large tortoiseshell hanging on a wooden pillar." />
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="../../img/IMG_4770.JPG" id="img_2" alt="Macro of a drowned lesser stag beetle." />
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="../../img/IMG_5229.JPG" id="img_3" alt="Black and yellow Volkswagen beetles in a lightbox." />
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="../../img/IMG_5696.JPG" id="img_4" alt="Domestic pigeon behind a brick wall." />
    </div>
    <a class="next" onclick="changeSlide(1, 0)">&#10097;</a>
  </div>
  <div class="points">
    <span class="circle" onclick="goToSlide(1, 0)"></span>
    <span class="circle" onclick="goToSlide(2, 0)"></span>
    <span class="circle" onclick="goToSlide(3, 0)"></span>
    <span class="circle" onclick="goToSlide(4, 0)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I log this in the console it prints out an empty list. I dont know why.
I also have this line:

```
let slides = document.getElementById("slideshow" + String(slideshow)).getElementsByClassName("slides");
```

This works fine. the first part (`document.getElementById("slideshow" + String(slideshow))`) works, it is the second part that isn't working (`.getElementsByClassName("circle")`).

I tried using a JQuery selector, but this also returned an empty list.

I also tried to remove the "points" div, but this didn't solve the problem.

Last but not least I tried to first select the "points" div and then the circles, still with an empty list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried this, but it still returned an empty list. I will include this in the post.

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` after `<a class="next" onclick="changeSlide(1, 0)">&#10097;</a>`. That ends the `slideshow0` div, so `.circle` isn't in the div.

Comment: Use an editor that automatically indents the code and it should help.

Comment: I formatted your HTML to show the part that is malformed  NOW you can see that the element with the ID as you noted does NOT have those children

Answer (score 0):

"You have an extra `</div>` after `<a class="next" onclick="changeSlide(1, 0)">&#10097;</a>`. That ends the slideshow0 div, so .circle isn't in the div. – Barmar"

Thanks, I overlooked it